# SQL query to retrieve results based on date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables with data:

customer:

```
cus_id             cus_name
1                  philip
2                  david
3                  morris
```

order:

```
 order_id   order_no    cus_id  ordr_status      order_ date_time
    1             123        1       d                      20121015 13:10:01
    2             456        1       c                      20121014 14:20:00
    3             789        2       d                      20121013 17:10:01
    4             767        2       c                      20121014 15:10:00
```

Based on this data, I want to retrieve both customer and order information if the order date time is  between 20121014 14:00:00 and 20121015 14:00:00 and if the the order status is  (d,c) and they have same oder id's.

Comment: Is this homework? Sounds a lot like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: Please edit your answer and show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: it' not home work dude.Are you able to do that?.select * from customer c join order o on (c.cus_id=c.cus_id) where to_char(o.order_date_time,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') not between '20121014 14:00:00' and '20121015 14:00:00'.But it is not wroking guys.I dont want to post exact tables due to privacy.

Comment: @user1726550, this isn't a place where people just write your code. Can people do it? Probably. Can they teach you much if you haven't put in effort? Not really.

Comment: should be "on (c.cus_id=o.cus_id)".  Edit your question to say you tried this query and it did not return any data.  Also note that ISO 8601 format in single quotes will compare as a date time.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you want this:

QUERY [**SQLFiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22c3c/7):

```
SELECT
c.cus_name
,o.order_no
,o.ordr_status
,o.[order_ date_time]
FROM
customer c
  RIGHT JOIN order1 o
  ON c.cus_id = o.cus_id
WHERE o.[order_ date_time] >='20121014 14:00:00'
  AND o.[order_ date_time] <='20121015 14:00:00'
  AND (o.ordr_status = 'd' OR o.ordr_status = 'c')
```

Result:

```
| CUS_NAME | ORDER_NO | ORDR_STATUS |  ORDER_ DATE_TIME |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   philip |      123 |           d | 20121015 13:10:01 |
|   philip |      456 |           c | 20121014 14:20:00 |
|    david |      767 |           c | 20121014 15:10:00 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for orders,

```
SELECT * 
FROM order
WHERE NOT order_date_time between '2012-10-14 14:00:00' and '2012-10-15 14:00:00'
```

Joining to customers is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It wont return any data.I want to retrieve orders 1,2 as two different rows.

Comment: @user1726550 I'm sorry, you said in the question you *did not* want orders between "20121014 14:00:00 and 20121015 14:00:00" but now you *do* want to see those orders?  Could you please clarify in the question?

Comment: Worked for me, had to modify the query little bit to suit my needs

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query in Oracle DB:

```
select * from table_name where to_char(date_field,'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') > '20190410 180614'
```

The above query fetches the records from a table, which were inserted into the table after 10-apr-2019 18:06:14 hrs.